# How to interact with a smart contract without ABI

Tags: security, abi, erc-20-approve

So I bought a scamcoin (I know). I have the contract and I've managed to decompile the bytecode. How can I interact with the contract to approve the token?
https://bscscan.com/address/0x2Ef6b6E7E95d9feA7b0eC98941a891b7bC8b4648#code

Comment: Don't waste your money anymore. Most scamcoins are programmed in such a way that only the owner can sell tokens, everybody else can only buy them.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have ABI you can interact with the smart contract by hand-crafting the `Data` payload for the transaction yourself.

Here are instructions [how to construct the data field payloads by hand](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-data-payloads-in-ethereum-transactions-354dbe995371).

If your question is only "How to approve token" then you can use [generic ERC-20 ABI](https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/).